# Why does Terraform fail to provision google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

While I am able to provision a single HTTP-triggered GCP cloud function and call it publicly, I can't seem to provision my second function to be called publicly as well.

I have the editor role assigned to my Terraform service account.

```
google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member.v2invoker: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error applying IAM policy for cloudfunctions cloudfunction "projects/myproject/locations/us-central1/functions/v2": Error setting IAM policy for cloudfunctions cloudfunction "projects/myproject/locations/us-central1/functions/v2": googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy' denied on resource 'projects/myproject/locations/us-central1/functions/v2' (or resource may not exist).
│ 
│   with google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member.v2invoker,
│   on main.tf line 460, in resource "google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member" "v2invoker":
│  460: resource "google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member" "v2invoker" {
```

Clarification - the function resource itself is provisioned correctly, only the `iam_member` resource isn't.

My Terraform config:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "v2" {
  name                  = "v2"
  runtime               = "nodejs12"
  available_memory_mb   = 128
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.functions.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.nodejs_functions.name
  entry_point           = "v2"

  trigger_http = true
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member" "v2invoker" {
  project        = google_cloudfunctions_function.v2.project
  region         = google_cloudfunctions_function.v2.region
  cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions_function.v2.name

  role   = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
  member = "allUsers"
}

output "function-v2" {
  value = google_cloudfunctions_function.v2.https_trigger_url
}
```

Added the terraform config for the first (successful) function:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "helloWorld" {
  name                  = "helloWorld"
  runtime               = "nodejs12"
  available_memory_mb   = 128
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.functions.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.nodejs_functions.name
  entry_point           = "helloWorld"

  trigger_http = true
}

# IAM entry so all users can invoke the function
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member" "invoker" {
  project        = google_cloudfunctions_function.helloWorld.project
  region         = google_cloudfunctions_function.helloWorld.region
  cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions_function.helloWorld.name

  role   = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
  member = "allUsers"
}

output "function-helloWorld" {
  value = google_cloudfunctions_function.helloWorld.https_trigger_url
}
```

The current service account used by terraform is one I created with "Editor" role.

Comment: What is your TF config?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary added to the original question

Comment: Do you have `setIamPolicy` permissions for the resource? Can you please add in the permissions you currently have?

Comment: Yes, I'm the admin of the project. I've got the exact terraform config on a different function, which is able to provision correctly.

Comment: Can you please also add the TF config for the other function? Strange...

Comment: Added it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to GCP IAM documentation:

> Note: The Editor role contains permissions to create and delete resources for most Google Cloud services. However, **it does not contain permissions to perform all actions for all services**. See the section above for more information on how to check if a role has the permissions that you need.

Your editor role definitely doesn't have access to perform the `cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy` action on the cloud function (as the error message mentions).

**Assign the [Cloud Functions Admin role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-functions-roles) (`roles/cloudfunctions.admin`) to the service account.**

It should definitely have all permissions required for anything cloud function-related, including but not limited to setting IAM policies on functions.